# boundedness of a sequence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let the real sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies $1 \leq a_0 < a_1 < a_2 <... \to \infty$ and let $n\in \mathbb{N}.$

Is the sequence $\displaystyle b_n=\frac{n}{a_n}$ bounded above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily--consider the sequence $a_0=1,a_1=1.2,$ and $a_n=\sqrt{n}$ for $n\ge2$ However, it *can* be--consider $a_n=n+1$.

Comment: Ah right. $\sqrt{n}$ instead of my $\log(n)+1$ may be an easier counter example. :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe, maybe not.

Take $a_n := n$, then $b_n = 1$ is bounded by $1$.

Take $a_n := \log(n+1)+1$, then $b_n \rightarrow \infty$ (which can be proven with l'Hospital for example).

Comment: The only problem with this (and my original answer) is that it doesn't meet the condition $1\le a_0.$

Comment: Oh, it starts with $a_0$, right. The $+1$ was designed to fix that. I‘ll edit my answer. :)